# Is there a term in lattice theory for this?

Tags: terminology, lattice-orders

Let $\mathfrak{A}$ be a lattice with join denoted $\cup$, meet denoted $\cap$, and least element $\bot$.

Consider a set $S\in\mathscr{P}\mathfrak{A}$ such that the following property holds (for every $a,b\in\mathfrak{A}$):

$a\in S\land b\in S\land a\cap b\ne\bot \Rightarrow a\cup b\in S$.

Is there a "standard" name for this property?

Comment: The best term I've come up is "quasi upward directed set". But it's entirely nonstandard (and also too long, as consists of four words).